# Meaning and usage of "head(s) AND tails above"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-origin, dialects

I've come across the expression "[head(s) and tails above](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heads%20and%20tails%20above&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)" (*the rest, the competition* etc; different from something like "can't make head or tail of something" i.e. can't figure it out/understand). I can't find information about this. It seemingly means *completely*.

Could you confirm its meaning and explain it a bit? Is it rare, is this expression recent and is it restricted to or typical of specific regions (Canada?)?

Comment: Far more common is *heads and shoulders above [the rest]*.

Comment: @Heartspring So it re-purposes the expression and uses "tails" instead of "shoulders"? More typical of the South maybe?

Comment: I haven't heard this use of the expression before, but [Mr Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22heads+and+tails+above%22) was quick to tell me about it.

Comment: So will it be "completely" (as in both heads and tails, the entire coin) or "by a good margin" (the head and the shoulders with respect to the whole body)? Is there an difference?

Comment: "Head and shoulders above" implies one stands taller than his or her peers.  It has to do with being superior in some way.  No one would assume he or she is so tall that all others are actually _beneath_ him or her, or even of less stature than his or her thighs.

Comment: I could easily believe this (imho, "incorrect") usage occurs more frequently in Canada simply because they have a relatively high proportion of non-native Anglophones ([over 20%](https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/as-sa/98-314-x/98-314-x2011001-eng.cfm)). Particularly given the OP here is primarily active on SO French Language, *and* first encountered the usage on [*Top Chef **Canada.***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Chef_Canada)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It wasn't Top Chef Canada, just Top Chef with Tom and Padma, the U.S. one. It's just Gail Simmons is a host judge and she's Canadian... Btw, the fact I'm mostly active on French language is not relevant, I'm not the one using this expression, in fact I had never heard of it before very recently.

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about *Top Chef*. But what you say there clearly doesn't rule out (and indeed seems to *support*) the possibility that this relatively uncommon new usage occurs more often in Canada than elsewhere. Since you presumably *live* in Canada, I'm sure most of the language (English *or* French) you're exposed to comes from other Canadians. And given you do say the first time you ever heard it was from a Canadian *Top Chef* judge, it might well be a predominantly Canadian ("emerging" / "incorrect", take your pick) usage.

Answer (score 6):

Personally I think ***heads** and **tails** above [the competition* is a kind of ["eggcorn"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn) misunderstanding / mishearing of the idiomatic standard ***head** and **shoulders** above*. Certainly the former has [almost no currency](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heads%20and%20tails%20above%20the%2Chead%20and%20shoulders%20above%20the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) by comparison...

[image]

The standard version makes sense - literally or figuratively "shorter" ones don't even reach as high as the "taller" one's shoulders.

But OP's version simply makes no sense anyway. How are tails relevant to being taller than something / someone else? Why are both ends pluralized (all bipeds have two shoulders, but who or what has two heads, or two tails?).

Perhaps some people use the term facetiously (compare [*Does the Pope shit in the woods?*](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-lm&q=does%20the%20pope%20shit%20in%20the%20woods), which I think *is* funny unless you find it offensive). But to me, *heads and tails above* just sounds ignorant.

Comment: Thanks, the first time I heard it was in _Top Chef_, s09e09 @45:00 in, Gail Simmons said "...the brisket was heads and tails above the other two briskets we ate today...". You can also find it in the singular, like [here](https://ew.com/article/2014/04/10/cbs-interview-colbert-letterman/) but contrary to the plural version, there are not enough hits for ngram to capture it (about 1% of the plural form).

Comment: I've got to say that cited context seems slightly odd for *any* version of figurative "much taller than" = "stands above the competition".  But maybe that's because I'm not cheffy-minded enough to easily envisage briskets publicly competing against each other for top position on the winners' pedestal! :)

Comment: In the same way that **head over heels in love** has taken over from the traditional idiom [over head and ears in love](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=head+over+heels+in%2C+over+head+and+ears+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: @KateBunting: I wonder if that's because the older version originally meant *[manhandled] **violently*** (grabbed "by head and ears" = "by the scruff of the neck"). That's to say, the original metaphoric allusion may have been to being "firmly grabbed / captivated / dominated" by love, where the modern version implies "disoriented / knocked over / toppled" by it. But I don't see any way to "explain" the ***heads and tails above*** version in the current context through a plausible alternative meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I've always understood it to mean _deeply submerged_.

Comment: @KateBunting: I wasn't familiar with *head and ears* anyway, but the full OED has * over head and ears: (so as to be) completely immersed; (figurative) (so as to be) **deeply immersed or involved** in something)* - first cite:?1521. Also *by (the) head and ears: (with reference to pulling, dragging, etc.) **roughly, violently; unceremoniously**. Also figurative. Cf. by (the) head and shoulders* - first cite 1590.